# How can I Build a Generic Method in c# to Query a Partition in a Given Azure Table

Tags: c#, azure, generics, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to build a generic method to return entries in a partition in a given Azure table. This is how it looks:

```
public class Table : ITable
    {
        private CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
        public Table()
        {
            var storageAccountSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureWebJobsStorage"].ToString();
            storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccountSettings);
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> RetrieveAllInPartition<T>(string tableReference, string partitionKey) where T : ITableEntity
        {
            var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableReference);
            var query = new TableQuery<T>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, partitionKey));
            var results = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync<T>(query,null);
            return results;
        }
    }
```

This doesn't compile I get:

> CS0310    'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless
>   constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TElement' in the generic
>   type or method
>   'CloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(TableQuery,
>   TableContinuationToken)'

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Comment: You edited your code and now the error message you provided and my answer doesn't make sense :)

Comment: @tovin, apologies; your answer is correct (expect that the new() constraint had to be the last constraint in the statement - which I edited before upvoting/checking) - also I realised that ExecuteQuery has no async method available so had to go with ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync - I'll edit references to ExecuteQuery in your answer too if that's ok with you? :)

Comment: sure :) don't forget to edit your error message as well

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to add `new()` constraint to your generic parameter:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> RetrieveAllInPartition<T>(string tableReference, string partitionKey) 
    where T : ITableEntity, new()
```

since `ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync` also has this constraint (as can be seen in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.cloudtable.executequerysegmentedasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_Table_CloudTable_ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync__1_Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_Table_TableQuery___0__Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_Table_TableContinuationToken_)).

This constraint is required by `ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync` because otherwise it won't be able to create instances of `T` for you. Please refer to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) to read more about the `new()` constraint.

Comment: HUGE HELP.  Thank you so much for this answer.